# Managing and manipulating Data in tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, datatables

I have two Tables in my Database. The first table has columns Serial,Date,Location, Type,Condition,Color,Loaned_To, ProductNumberREF, and Department.

The next table has Product Number,Type,Brand,and Price.

With this system i am able to alter the Price of all items in the Main table without going one by one. But now i am running into a problem.

I'm creating a Total money spend Label that i want to populate with all the sums of prices of all the items in a Gridview. How do i add the Sum of all prices in a table that doesn't contain prices but has to reference to another table?

[image: Here is a Visual]

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand SpentCheck = new SqlCommand("Selct Sum(Price) From Items");
```

this Code was my initial attempt till i realized  PRICE doesn't exist in ITEMS. So how do i get the sum of all Prices in ITEMS?

UPDATE#####

[image]

I tries the first answers Suggestions this is were i am now

Comment: YEa to get the Total Price of all Items but i cant do that cause there is no Price column in Item. How would i point to the price a Serial Number has with the corresponding product number

Comment: Why dont use inner join https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Also im using a LinqSource so i cant use the query builder to organize it

Comment: You are using ADO.NET or LINQ?

Comment: @GrantWinney it looks like the op is mapping one `ProductNumber` to multiple `Items`

Comment: Yes you are right i am mapping multiple items

Comment: Grant what do you mean what would i change in order to fix it im New to SQL

Comment: Pass the conn in sqlcommand constructor. Like this:  `SqlCommand SpentCheck = new SqlCommand("Selct Sum(Price) From Items", conn);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an SQL [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
SELECT
    SUM(Price)
FROM
    Items
      INNER JOIN ProductNumber ON Items.Product_NumberREF = ProductNumber.ProductNumber
```